# Git and sharing /bin with select users

Tags: git, sharing, restrict

Sort of new to Git, but I'm thinking of moving over from SVN.  I know that Git does not allow you to block off a single directory from users, so it's all or nothing in terms of access, but a frequent scenario I have is that I want to use source control for a whole project, but share only the /bin directory with a client.  Are there strategies or best practices for this?  I'm looking at BitBucket as a host, so I wouldn't be hosting Git myself, therefore I don't think I can make any modifications to how Git works.

What do you guys do?

Comment: If the client shouldn't have access to the source, why would you give them access to your source control system?

Comment: I often will give SVN access to the deployment files.  I want clients to be able to get the latest version of those files, and so SVN works well for that, but sometimes I don't want to let them have the source files.

Comment: Source control systems usually deal badly with versioning binaries anyway; some other deployment strategy is probably a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `bin` directory in a separate repository.  If it *must* be a subdirectory, use submodules.

Comment: That was my first thought, although I was wondering if there were any "accepted" ways of doing this.  From my reading, submodules have some weird issues?  But that's mainly if you have to pull from them frequently.  I guess if it was just a /bin folder, you'd mainly be pushing builds there?

Comment: The "accepted" way is going to be using a separate repo, that's why I said only use a submodule if you must.